# Domain object vs model object

Tags: model, separation-of-concerns

why is a domain object  usually not used as model object? Because of the topic sparation of concerns ?

I understand a model object is created to be displayed in an application. It can contain adapted properties and behavior for my views. It can contain properties from different domain objects.

A domain object represents a pure entity of my domain ( entity of my database) and usually it has not behavior, contains only data. A domain object contains only data.It is a data class. Is it correct?

Thanks